# dot sourcing causes ignoring changes in PS script files by PS console

Tags: powershell

I have those three files:

**Glass.ps1**

```
class Glass
{
    # Properties
    [int32]$Size
    [int32]$CurrentAmount

    # Constructors
    Glass () { }

    Glass ($Size, $Amount)
    {
        $this.Size = $Size
        $this.CurrentAmount = $Amount
    }

    # Methods   
    [Boolean] Fill ([int32]$volume)
    {
        Write-Host "Calling PARENT class"
        return $true
    }

    [Boolean] Drink ([int32]$amount)
    {
        return $true        
    }
}
```

**AnyGlass.ps1**

```
class AnyGlass : Glass
{
    [String]$Name

    AnyGlass () {
        $this.Size = 6                  # parent property
        $this.CurrentAmount = 0         # parent property
        $this.Name = "My glass"         # child property
    }

    # Methods overload
    [void] Fill ([int]$volume, [string]$Warning)
    {   
        Write-Host "Calling CHILD class"
        reurn $true
    }
}
```

**runIncluded.ps1**

```
. ".\Glass.ps1"
. ".\AnyGlass.ps1"

$glass = New-Object -TypeName Glass
$anyGlass = New-Object -TypeName AnyGlass
$anyGlass.Fill(1)
```

If I start new PS console and run `runIncluded.ps1` then the output is as expected:

```
PS C:\Users\wakatana\Desktop\ps\> .\runIncluded.ps1
Calling PARENT s class
True
```

But If I change `Write-Host "Calling PARENT class"` e.g. to `Write-Host "Calling PARENT class NEW VERSION"` and I run `runIncluded.ps1` again (from the same PS console) then I get the same output as previous. If I restart the console then it works just OK and i get `Calling PARENT class NEW VERSION`. If I put content of three mentioned file into one, then run it from console, then edit it, then run again, everything is working fine. Is it necessary to somehow reset the environment before running new scripts or what is the problem?

PS: To me this looks like broken PS, I guess this might be related to my other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59258282/powershell-ignores-add-type-unless-it-is-copied-and-pasted-directly-to-console)

My OS: Windows 10 Home - Latest Updates

Comment: Can you double-check your ```AnyGlass.ps1``` example above? When I run that I get ```Invalid return statement within void method.``` because you've declared the method with return type ```[void]``` but you've got the line ```reurn $true``` in the definition (which should probably also be ```reTurn $true``` anyway...).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Class from Memory in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838107/remove-class-from-memory-in-powershell)