# Cannot convert the "X" value of type "X" to type "X"

Tags: powershell

I can't work out why:

```
Exception calling "GetSites" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot convert the
"WS.WSErrorObject" value of type "WS.WSErrorObject" to type "WS.WSErrorObject"."
At ...
+ WS.WSSiteEntity[] $sites = $webServiceProxy.GetSites([ref] $wsError)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSInvalidCastException
```

The code is quite simple:

```
$webServiceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $elevateUri -Credential $credential -Namespace WS

$wsError = New-Object -TypeName WS.WSErrorObject

WS.WSSiteEntity[] $sites = $webServiceProxy.GetSites([ref] $wsError)
```

It's similar to [PowerShell 5 and classes - Cannot convert the "X" value of type "X" to type "X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804102/powershell-5-and-classes-cannot-convert-the-x-value-of-type-x-to-type-x), so I think it has to do with there being multiple copies of the same type but I still can't work  it out.

I have tried with full autogenerated typenames (i.e. not using a namespace for the Web Service proxy) and the result is the same.

I've tried to use weak typing but don't know how to declare wsError for the reference without constructing a new object and giving it a type.

Comment: Try `$wsError = $null` instead of `New-Object`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.  Would you believe I tried $wsError = nil and $wError = null. So close :-)  I am a PowerShell newbie...

Comment: Mathias, it worked. If you would like to write that up as a solution, I will accept.